# Which pronoun is correct?

Tags: grammar

What is correct:  If you or your attorneys have questions, *they* should call or email me.  OR  If you  or your attorneys have questions, *you* should call or email me.

Comment: "If you or your attorneys have questions, call or email me."

Answer (score 3):

In this case it should be "you" since you're referring to both "you and your attorneys".